# Why does changing and centering the title of my contents page push the title down?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I would like to change the default title of the contents page from "Contents" to "Table of Contents". Additionally, I would also like to horizontally center the title.

An MWE of my code without any changes to the title of the contents page is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 2.54 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Random Variables}

\subsection{Definition}

\end{document}
```

Then, I tried to change my code as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 2.54 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}

\renewcommand\contentsname{\center{Table of Contents}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Random Variables}

\subsection{Definition}

\end{document}
```

Adding the line `\renewcommand\contentsname{\center{Table of Contents}}` does indeed change the title of my contents page to "Table of Contents" which has also become horizontally centered. However, the title is now pushed downwards slightly (relative to the original code) for some reason.

I have two queries.

Firstly, why does adding the line `\renewcommand\contentsname{\center{Table of Contents}}` also push the title downwards? Secondly, if I want my new title to appear as how the default title did i.e. without getting pushed downwards, how should I tweak my code or what should the correct code be?

P.S. I am quite new to LaTeX, so any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `\center`  is the internal implementation of the `center` environment and should never be used as a command (and does not take an argument). `center` adds vertical space. `\centering` is the command form, (although the `\...name`  commands are not intended to have any formatting commands)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see! Could you put this as an answer so I can accept it? I will try it out tomorrow but I’ve got high hopes that it will work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\center` is the internal implementation of the `center` environment and should never be used as a command (and does not take an argument). `center` adds vertical space. `\centering` is the command form, (although the `\...name` commands are not intended to have any formatting commands) so as a quick hack

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{\centering Table of Contents}
```

would work although really this is abusing the system. LaTeX introduced the `\...name` commands specifically to hold *plain text* fixed strings *without* formatting, so that documents may be localised changing the fixed texts (eg to another language) without having to re-implement the formatting.

The formatting should be specified by the document class, which for article is

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
```

So if you want just this to have a centered heading and not change other `\section*` then you could add `\centering` here as in

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\centering\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
\makeatother
```